# Recursively copy remote SFTP directories without write permissions (to local)

Tags: macos, openssh, sftp

I see lots of questions related to this, but not all my constraints so I'll start with my constraints.

Constraints:

- I want to recursively copy a remote directory.
- I can't control the remote server setup at all.
- I don't have write permissions to that directory on the remote machine.
- When I try `get -r`, it copies the directory *without local* write permissions either.
- Then, when it tries to recursively copy nested files and folders in the remote directory, it gets an error in the *local* directory where it didn't give me have write permissions.
- I can't install new software on my machine. (need a pure `sftp` solution with "OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3")

Question:

> Can I recursively copy the remote directories with pure `sftp` and no *local* permissions error?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: OpenSSH 8.5 released 2021-03 fixes this problem; see http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.5 under Bugfixes the item for bz#3222 .

Aside: OpenSSH 7.9 was released in 2018-10; it can't have "[come] on [a] Mac ~5 years ago". You've gotten updated somehow.

You're right; `download_dir_internal` in `sftp-client.c` creates a new local directory with the same permissions as the remote one, if available, except masked by 01777 -- i.e. excluding suid and sgid which are pretty rare and very likely don't occur in your case. The `-p` (or `-P`) flag is needed to set permissions for *files* but is ignored for directories.

However, if the directory already exists, sftp ignores the EEXIST error. So if you first create all the (empty) directories *with* write permissions and then do `get -r` it should work. I don't see any way in sftp to *list* recursively, so unless you aleady know the directory structure or have a way to execute something like `find /mydir -type d` on the remote, this gets a bit ugly:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash     # or other location as necessary
REMOTE=(user@host) # array so can add _separated_ options like -i idfile -P port if needed
IFS=$'\n'
all=( )
new=( $( echo ls -n | sftp ${REMOTE[@]} | awk '/^d/{print substr($0,57)}' ) )
while [[ ${#new[@]} -gt 0 ]]; do
        all+=( "${new[@]}" )
        new=( $( printf "ls -n %s\n" "${new[@]}" \
            | sftp ${REMOTE[@]} | awk '/^d/{print substr($0,57)}' ) )
done
mkdir "${all[@]}" # with umask NOT including 200!
# or if (maybe) large enough to hit ARG_MAX
printf '%s\n' "${all[@]}" | xargs mkdir
# if dirnames (can) contain any SP TAB " ' \
# use -d'\n' on GNU but you're on your own otherwise 
# (and Macs mostly don't have GNU)
```

(Not tested on Mac because I don't have one, but I believe everything here is portable except as noted.)